# Cypress timeout when I try to interact with browser

Tags: javascript, jenkins, timeout, cypress

I have 175 cypress tests that run locally with no problems , but when I try to run on jenkins from specific test when the test try to interact with the browser I get a timeout , and then all the tests fail on the same timeout when they try to interact with the browser.
the test that fails  :

```
describe('Data Source bulk actions', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.task('dropDB').then(() => {
      cy.viewport(1920, 1080);
      cy.login();
      cy.closeOnboardingModal();
    });
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    cy.logout();
  });

  it('bulk of enable/disabled', () => {
    createSeveralDs();
```

the error I get :
Error Message
Timed out after waiting `60000ms` for your remote page to load.  Your page did not fire its `load` event within `60000ms`.  You can try increasing the `pageLoadTimeout` value in `/e2e-tests/cypress-ci.json` to wait longer.  Browsers will not fire the `load` event until all stylesheets and scripts are done downloading.  When this `load` event occurs, Cypress will continue running commands.  Because this error occurred during a `before each` hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: `Entity Source`
Stacktrace
CypressError: Timed out after waiting `60000ms` for your remote page to load.

Your page did not fire its `load` event within `60000ms`.

You can try increasing the `pageLoadTimeout` value in `/e2e-tests/cypress-ci.json` to wait longer.

Browsers will not fire the `load` event until all stylesheets and scripts are done downloading.

When this `load` event occurs, Cypress will continue running commands.

Because this error occurred during a `before each` hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: `Entity Source`
at timedOutWaitingForPageLoad (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:156924:13)
at https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:157907:16
at tryCatcher (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:10609:23)
at https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:5731:41
at tryCatcher (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:10609:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8544:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8601:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8646:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8722:18)
at _drainQueueStep (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:5316:12)
at _drainQueue (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:5309:9)
at Async.../../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js.Async._drainQueues (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:5325:5)
at Async.drainQueues (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:5195:14)
From Your Spec Code:
at Context.eval (https://bigid-ui/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/support/index.js:866:6)

any idea ? I tried to call visit from the test and not from the before
I tried to delete onBeforeLoad from login function .
also tried to change visit('/') to visit('') , also didn't work.
I also tried to update cypress from 6.2.1 to 6.3.0 also didn't help .

Comment: Maybe try setting up Cypress so that it takes a screenshot or video of the test, then that way you can get a better understanding of how the test is failing.

Comment: I assume you are running your tests in a headless browser on Jenkins, have you also tried that locally?

Comment: @ShafiqJetha I have a screenshot and a video , as I said it fails on login (the first interaction with browser) so nothing to see there.

Comment: @SimonD  locally it works fine  , it happens only on jenkins.

Comment: I'm under the assumption that cypress starts recording from the moment the browser starts up, not from when the test runs. If there's nothing being displayed then maybe some pre-conditions are not being fulfilled and that's what's causing the test to fail?

Comment: @ShafiqJetha no problems with the test itself  because it passes locally , also what happens is that cy.visit fails on the timeout problem so the page is still empty , the problem is that I don't know what is causing the problem because it happens randomly .

Comment: were you able to find a solution @DeebAndrawis? Im having this locally, i see the website being loaded but visit waits and eventually fails after 60s.

Comment: the problem I faced was that the tests stop in the middle of run - looks like cypress can`t work with all the logs from nginx so after a lot of tests it crash - I disabled the nginx logs and it worked for me .